# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. Unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I was trying to build my Unity game for android and I face this issue, please help with what to do. I am a beginner in unity and do not have much experience.

Here is the error messages:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using ProjectExecutionServices.createTaskExecuter() as there is a problem with parameter #22 of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry.
> Cannot create service of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry using ProjectExecutionServices.createReservedFileLocationRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<ReservedFileSystemLocation>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using ProjectExecutionServices.createTaskExecuter() as there is a problem with parameter #22 of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry.
> Cannot create service of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry using ProjectExecutionServices.createReservedFileLocationRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<ReservedFileSystemLocation>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 6s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)


CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.5f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.5f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using ProjectExecutionServices.createTaskExecuter() as there is a problem with parameter #22 of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry.
> Cannot create service of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry using ProjectExecutionServices.createReservedFileLocationRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<ReservedFileSystemLocation>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using ProjectExecutionServices.createTaskExecuter() as there is a problem with parameter #22 of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry.
> Cannot create service of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry using ProjectExecutionServices.createReservedFileLocationRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<ReservedFileSystemLocation>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 6s
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:337)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)


Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 297 seconds (296813 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)


UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002be] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

I have no idea how to fix this issue. Please help. :(

When I searched for other answers with the same question that I had, they all have given solutions to switch off Ads or similar, but I don't have any Ads in my game at all.

PS: I use Photon PUN for the sake of Multiplayer access.

Comment: You need to search the web with these keywords in mind. There are quite few solutions.: Cannot create service of type TaskExecuter using ProjectExecutionServices.createTaskExecuter() as there is a problem with parameter #22 of type ReservedFileSystemLocationRegistry.

Comment: I did try it, and I tried it just now after your advice but all the results I get is with android studio, not unity and does not help me :(. Any ideas?

Comment: If you can help me out, please do because I really need to build my app...

Comment: I'd try to first build on empty unity project to make sure there is no issue with the unity itself. and then gradually add libraries like Photon. You need to debug one piece by one in the case if nothing else works. Optimally would be great if you'd build on real android device, not emulator.

Comment: Wait a minute... Should I build on an actual device? I thought if I did build an APK would be saved on my computer and then I can shift it to my mobile and install it? Therefore I am not using an emulator nor an actual device. I am new to this. Also, I shall try to build on empty unity project right now and let you know.

Comment: Unity has a great way of sending a build to your real device. You just connect it via USB (need to set developer settings in your android device and install ADB drivers) and just hit Build & Run. Creating an .apk and sending to device is slow and incorrect process because it doesn't show you the LOG - what is happening on device. So it's hard to debug.

Comment: I have tried to build an empty unity project but it does not work. It gives me the same errors, what do I do?

Comment: Didn't work, check chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue if you are building directly onto the external drive. Try to build directly on your hard drive.